# Multiple Google access permissions for a desktop application

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-contacts-api

I'm writing a desktop application in C# that should be able to access all users on a Google Apps "account" an retrieve calendar-events for each user. I have added the Calendar API and the Admin SDK to my "project".

Both methods (below) works fine on their own but when I want to authorize my app for both APIs I get the following permission errors.

Insufficient Permission [403]

invalid_grant", Description:"Token has been revoked.

This made me wonder if it was possible to ask for all permissions when the application starts, instead of authorizing the "features" separately?

```
    static string[] CalendarScopes = {CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
    static string[] DirectoryScopes = {    DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly };

    private static void GoogleCalendar()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                CalendarScopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        //request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void GoogleDirectory()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                DirectoryScopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Directory API service.
        var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        UsersResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.List();
        request.Customer = "my_customer";
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = UsersResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.Email;

        // List users.

        IList<User> users = null;

        try
        {
            users = request.Execute().UsersValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Users:");
        if (users != null && users.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var userItem in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", userItem.PrimaryEmail,
                    userItem.Name.FullName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No users found.");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: what are the errors you get? Yes, you can request an access token with all the scopes you will require for your application. Although this is not recommended.

Comment: I have updated my question with the exceptions. Why isn't it recommended to use an access token for multiple scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! I figured out, how to solve the problem, and it was actually quite simple.

The solution was, to "merge" the methods. This meant, that I only have to check the credentials once, using the access token. I also added directory to the scope-array.

```
    static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly };

    private static void GoogleThis()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var eventService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest eventRequest = eventService.Events.List("primary");
        eventRequest.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        eventRequest.ShowDeleted = false;
        eventRequest.SingleEvents = true;
        //request.MaxResults = 10;
        eventRequest.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = eventRequest.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
        }
        // Create Directory API service.
        var dirService = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        UsersResource.ListRequest dirRequest = dirService.Users.List();
        dirRequest.Customer = "my_customer";
        dirRequest.MaxResults = 10;
        dirRequest.OrderBy = UsersResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.Email;

        // List users.
        IList<User> users = null;
        try
        {
            users = dirRequest.Execute().UsersValue;
            Console.WriteLine("Users:");
            if (users != null && users.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var userItem in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", userItem.PrimaryEmail,
                        userItem.Name.FullName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No users found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```